# Share @ViewModelScoped dependency between different ViewModels scoped to the same nested NavGraph

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

Hilt allowes you to use `@ViewModelScoped` and `ViewModelComponent`.
As stated in the [Medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-hilts-viewmodelcomponent-53b46515c4f4) each ViewModel will receive its own instance of `@ViewModelScoped` dependency.

What would be nice is to have scope which allowes you to have something like `@NavGraphScoped`.

Let's say you have `PlaceListDefinition` navigation flow that allowes you to define list of places. The navigation flow is represented as a nested `NavGraph` and following screens:

- `PlaceListScreen` (depends on `PlaceListViewModel`)
- `PlacePickerScreen` (depends on `PlacePickerViewModel`)

Let's say they both have complex logic so it's better **not** to use shared ViewModel.
(It would also allow to reuse screen + view model in different part of the app).

Here is [draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfhD1.png) of the needed scopes.

For now I use a workaround, where there is only one "wrapper" ViewModel (which is true Android `ViewModel` - `PlaceListDefinitionViewModel` which uses `@ViewModelScopedList<Places>` and provides it to sub-ViewModels.

The dependency:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object PlaceListModule {
   // I am ommiting @JvmSupressWildcards for readibility
   fun providePlacesList() = MutableStateFlow<emptyList<Place>>()
}
```

The "wrapper" ViewModel scoped to nested NavGraph that provides sub-viewmodels with the dependency scopend:

```kotlin
@ViewModelScoped
class PlaceListDefinitionViewModel @Inject constructor(
   // I am ommiting @JvmSupressWildcards for readibility
   places: MutableStateFlow<List<Place>>
): ViewModel() { // this is the "real" Android Architecture Components' ViewModel
   val placeListViewModel = PlaceListViewModel() // NOT Android ViewModel, just simple class
   val placePickerViewModel = PlacePickerViewModel() // NOT Android ViewModel, just simple class
}
```

Then I could use it like it (Screens are composables, am not sure whether it could be reused in fragment-based architecutre)

```kotlin
NavHost(/* params */) {
   // other routes ...
   navigation(route = "place_list_definition", startDestination = "place_list") {
      composable(route = "place_list") {
         val viewModel = remember {navController.getBackStackEntry("place_list_definition") }
         PlaceListScreen(wrapperViewModel.placeListViewModel)
      }
      composable(route = "place_picker") {
         val viewModel = remember {navController.getBackStackEntry("place_list_definition") }
         PlacePickerScreenWrapper(wrapperViewModel.placePickerViewModel)
      }
   }
}
```

**It would be nice to have an official out-of-the-box solution for the specific use case, which may be quite common requirement...**

Comment: put it inside the parent Subcomponent change `PlaceListModule` annotations to `@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)` or even `SingletonComponent::class`

Comment: but it use the same instance across multiple navigation flows, wouldn't it? :)
That means when user clicks a button "new place list" and is navigated to the "place_list_definition" NavGraph, they would see the previous places (and should see empty list once they left the NavGraph and reentered it)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - just use dagger normally for non Android archtiecture classes?  Currently you forego this by creating objects manually inside your top view model - those can  just be injected, both with the same instance of `places`

Comment: Actually I wanted Android architecture ViewModels but I didn't have the right scope for them (It would be `@NavGraphScope`).
But you are right, using non-Android sub-ViewModels we could simply scope them to the parent ViewModel with `@ViewModelScoped` and use Hilt for `places` injection. Thanks a lot @MarkKeen, I'll update the post :)

Comment: The root of the issue is that Hilt does not provide means to nest ViewModelComponent dependencies. There are plenty of reasons to want Android ViewModels associated with each of your child Views/screens in a flow and have them share resources (e.g. data sources), but this is not possible out of the box without having data sources exist at a Scope wrapping the flow UX, and which is hugely undesirable for single Activity architecture (you have to manually reset your data sources each time you start a flow instead of them being automatically destroyed along with their relevant Scope).